# why the perl regular expression is not identifying the value

Tags: regex, sas

I have the below data where I am trying to identify the '-0.00' value with regular expression but that seems not working , please let me know why and provide a working solution

```
data master;
  input val$ ;
match = prxmatch('m/^\-\d[0]\.\d[0]+/o', strip(val));
  datalines;
-0.00
-0.05
0.00
;
run;
```

here i am using the below regex

```perl
\- to detect -
\d[0] detect digit which is 0
\. detect a dot
\d[0]+ detect digit which is 0 and happens to be more than once
```

I tried using the below and it works but i dont want to use this approach

match = prxmatch('m/^-0.00/o', strip(val));

Comment: `\d[0] detect digit which is 0` If you want to detect a zero, why not use an actual plain `0` ?

Comment: yes i can, but then \d[0], should also work right?, i want to know why isn't working

Comment: My understanding is that \d[0] matches any digit, *followed by* 0,  not 'digit which *is* 0'

Comment: Your pattern `^\-\d[0]\.\d[0]+` matches at least two digits before and two digits after the dot, where the first of the two is a single digit and the second one is a zero. See what it currently matches https://regex101.com/r/GGFIG0/1 Do you mean a pattern like `^-0+\.0+$` or `^-0\.0` ?

Answer (score 0):

- `\d` detects any digit
- `0` will detect 0
- `[0]` will also detect 0
- `\d[0]` you are asking to detect any digit followed by 0

in SAS you might be better served with `val_n = INPUT(val,??best.)`